# How do I render name associated with foreign key as a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I would like to render the name associated with my foreign key as a link. How do I do this? I have tried

```
<link_to (painting.artist.name), artist_path(@artists) >
```

and

```
<link_to <%= painting.artist.name %>, artist_path(@artists) >
```

but neither work, and I am not getting anything on Google. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you are have bad erb tags, see if this will work for you.

```
<%= link_to painting.artist.name , artist_path(@artists) %>
```

Happy Hacking

Comment: merci beaucoup!!!! I had to change the `(@artist)` to `<%= link_to painting.artist.name , artist_path(painting.artist_id) %>` but otherwise you were right on!!! much appreciated :)

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help.  :)